# Force downloading files with foreign characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, force-download

How can I force the download of files whose file name contains more characters than English, for example Swedish, Norwegian like ö ä å . It's working perfect if the file is without ö ä å but not if file name holds Swedish characters.

The following is the code that I use to open files.

```
$file_id = $_GET['f'];

$sql =  " SELECT * ".
        " FROM attachment ".
        " WHERE attachment_id = ".$file_id." ".

        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $filename = $row['filename'];
        $USER_ID = $row['user_id'];
        $DIRECTORY_ID = $row['directory_id'];
        $target_path = "upload/".$USER_ID."/".$DIRECTORY_ID."/";


// And the function is :
function Download($path, $speed = null)
{
    if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        $file = @fopen($path, 'rb');
        $speed = (isset($speed) === true) ? round($speed * 1024) : 524288;

        if (is_resource($file) === true)
        {
            set_time_limit(0);
            ignore_user_abort(false);

            while (ob_get_level() > 0)
            {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf('%u', filesize($path)));
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

            while (feof($file) !== true)
            {
                echo fread($file, $speed);

                while (ob_get_level() > 0)
                {
                    ob_end_flush();
                }

                flush();
                sleep(1);
            }

            fclose($file);
        }

        exit();
    }

    return false;

    }

        Download($target_path.$filename);
```

I have used:

```
$filename = urlencode($filename); 
$filename =  htmlentities($filename, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

and

```
$path = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $path)
```

But nothing is working.
I want to thank you in advance and  Any help you can give will be greatly appreciated. 
Jonas.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

and be sure that you save your PHP Source file as utf-8.

Comment: Thank you Amed for your response.  Where shall I put the header? Together with those Another headers or some where else? I puted it together with those headers inside the function but it didn't work. It is the same problem. Thank you again.

Comment: with your header functions at the top :)
and be sure that your php file has been saved as utf-8 encoding.